# How to explode in foreach loop and implode to one string

Tags: php

i need to explode a string in peaces and delete some caracters. Finally i would like to put this string horizontally together.

This is what i try:

```
$string = "34 asdfadfadf.*****23 vgadfsdfasdf.*****46 asdfasdfadf.";
$arr = explode("*****", $string);
foreach ($arr as $val) {

$val = trim(substr($val, 0, 2));
$arr_neu[] = $val;                                                                      
}
$array_neu = implode(" ", $arr);  
fwrite($flog, "\nstring neu:" . $array_neu);
```

and this is what i get:
34 asdfadfadf.*****23 vgadfsdfasdf.*****46 asdfasdfadf. 34 23 46

I only need the numbers 34 23 46!

thanks!

Comment: `$array_neu = preg_replace('/[^\d ]/', '', $string);`

Comment: it works! but there are sometimes numeric into the string.

Comment: `~\D+~` = not digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with `preg_replace` function:

```
$s = '34 asdfadfadf.*****23 vgadfsdfasdf.*****46 asdfasdfadf.';
$result = trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9 ]+/', '', $s));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
34 23 46
```

**----------**

If the string could contain multiple consecutive spaces - change the above approach to the following:

```
$result = trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', ' ', $s));
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of code you are using wrong variable to implode data

change your code to

```
$string = "34 asdfadfadf.*****23 vgadfsdfasdf.*****46 asdfasdfadf.";
$arr = explode("*****", $string);
foreach ($arr as $val) {

$val = trim(substr($val, 0, 2));
$arr_neu[] = $val;                                                                      
}
$array_neu = implode(" ", $arr_neu); // <--------change here. Use $arr_neu
fwrite($flog, "\nstring neu:" . $array_neu);
```

Comment: i get this error now. Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in line 6

Comment: this is my new code:

$string = "34 asdfadfadf.*****23 vgadfsdfasdf.*****46 asdfasdfadf.";
$arr = explode("*****", $string);
foreach ($arr as $val) {

$val = trim(substr($val, 0, 2));
$arr_neu[] = $val;                                                                      
}
$arr_neu = implode(" ", $arr_neu);  
fwrite($flog, "\nstring neu:" . $arr_neu);  
error:Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in Line 6 // Line 6 == $arr_neu[] = $val;

Answer (score 0):

you just change `implode` value to `$arr_neu` instead of `$arr`

```
<?php

$string = "34 asdfadfadf.*****23 vgadfsdfasdf.*****46 asdfasdfadf.";
$arr = explode("*****", $string);
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    $val = trim(substr($val, 0, 2));
    $arr_neu[] = $val;                                                                      
}
$array_neu = implode(" ", $arr_neu);  
fwrite($flog, "\nstring neu:" . $array_neu);
```